# I got my useEffect hook called every render after i put dinamic import into it and i don't know how to fix that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm studying and making MERN blog by video on youtube. I finished the project on video and started modifying it by myself for more practice. So I added pagination with filtering to blogs to get my site better and it was working. But a lot of actions were done in parent component were was useEffect hook with dispatch of AsyncThunk function inside it. So I put all that actions and useEffect hook inside pagination component and made dinamic import inside useEffect hook and inside this promise I get, I dispatch needed AsyncThunk function.

And now it works, I get responses from server, but there is a problem: my useEffect never stops and always calls dispatch. However I already have my redux state changed with response data from server.

I tried adding import into dependency, but that didn't work. And eslint also has no problem with useEffect dependency.

This is parent component were I put pagination component:

```
export const MainPage = () => {
    const { loading, popularPosts } = useSelector(state => state.post)

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <div className="text-xl text-center text-white py-10">
                Loading...
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className='max-w-[900px] mx-auto py-10'>
            <div className="flex justify-between gap-8">
                <Pagination
                    request={'getAllPosts'}
                />
                <div className="basis-1/5">
                    <div className='text-xs uppercase text-white'>
                        POPULAR:
                    </div>

                    {
                        popularPosts?.map((post, index) => (
                            <PopularPosts key={index} post={post} />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is pagination component logic part:

```
export function Pagination({ request }) {
    const location = useLocation()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const path = location.pathname
    const { postsNum, loading, posts, page } = useSelector(state => state.post)

    console.log(postsNum, loading, posts, page)

    const currentPage = (new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('page')) === page ?
        page :
        (new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('page'))

    let filter = (new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('filter')) === null ?
        '' :
        (new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('filter'))
    console.log(currentPage, filter)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('message')
        import('../../redux/fetures/post/postSlice').then((res) => {
            dispatch(res[request]({currentPage, filter}))
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }, [dispatch, currentPage, filter, request])

    filter = filter === '' ? '-createdAt' : filter
```

This is function which i dispatch:

```
export const getAllPosts = createAsyncThunk('post/getAllPosts', async ({ currentPage, filter }) => {
    try {
        let dataRes = []

        filter = filter[0] ? filter.replace(/\+/g, '%2B') : filter
        filter = filter ? '&filter=' + filter :
            ''

        if (currentPage && currentPage !== 'null') {
            const { data } = await Axios.get(`/posts/?page=${currentPage}${filter}`)
            dataRes = data
        } else {
            const { data } = await Axios.get(`/posts/?${filter.slice(1)}`)
            dataRes = data
        }
        console.log(dataRes)

        return dataRes
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Extra reducer of getAllPosts:

```
// GET ALL POSTS
        [getAllPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true
            state.status = null
        },
        [getAllPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.posts = action.payload?.responsePosts
            state.postsNum = action.payload?.postsNum
            state.popularPosts = action.payload?.popularPosts
        },
        [getAllPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false
        },
```

If you need more information provided just ask. This is my first quesion on Stack Overflow and I don't know how well to specify my question.

EDIT: I edited code to make it visible that i pass from parent component function name to dinamically import it then and dispatch it.

I also found problem it was in MainPage component in part where i check if the response is loading. After i commented it useEffect stopped make infinite loop.

Now i want to know why it made my code work as it worked before solution

Comment: ***Why*** are you dynamically importing the post slice? Just import it normally and dispatch `getAllPosts`. Do you know which dependency is changing each render cycle to cause the effect to run each time? `dispatch` is a stable reference, so that leaves either `currentPage` or `filter` to be changing each cycle. It may also be the case that the entire `Pagination` is remounted for some reason. Can you [edit] to clarify what debugging steps have been taken and to include a complete [mcve]?

Comment: I dinamically import post slice to get access to asyncThunk functions dinamically, because i want reuse pagination component in other page components. This will help me minimize code needed in page components to add pagination to them. All i will need is just pass name of asyncThunk and it will be dinamically imported and used.

Comment: I also tried making currentPage and filter static, but this didn't help to stop useEffect to be called again and again. I also tried directly import getAllPosts and dispatch it, but this also didn't changed situation. @DrewReese

Comment: If i import postSlice directly i can't access getAllPosts

Comment: I still fail to see what exactly is dynamic about your code here, but when `getAllPosts` is dispatched, `state.post.loading` is true and `Pagination` is unmounted. When loading completes, `Pagination` is mounted and the `useEffect` hook is called and dispatches `getAllPosts`. Do you see now how the render looping is created?

Comment: @DrewReese, yes now I usnderstand the problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are reassigning filter after calling use effect and the use Effect is dependent on filter, since use effect is dependent on filter change filter cause use effect to rerun hence you stuck in the loop. Try to remove filter after use Effect or call it inside use effect with return null. Hope It helps.

Comment: I tried to comment line where i reasign filter and unfortunantly it didn't helped.

Comment: `filter` is reassigned *after* the `useEffect` call, so that won't retrigger the effect.